# when i try to import the older android project of around 2016 A.D version. The gradle build suddenly fails, what should i do to overcome

Tags: android, gradle, import

Gradle sync failed: Unable to load class 'javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSchema'.
This is an unexpected error. Please file a bug containing the idea.log file. (13 s 184 ms)

Comment: you can find idea.log file under following directory `C:\Users\xyz\AppData\Local\Google\AndroidStudio20xx.x\log` . Give a try to look into actual issue.

Answer (score 0):

`If you want to execute the former project. When Android studio is unable to sync the Gradle, you can run the project by copying all the code to another project with the same name and make sure the project name matches with older projects.  If it does not match, copy and paste the layout, java and the asset of the same name onto the new project.

Answer (score 0):

Please check for following to debug -

1. idea.log - which is available under (Windows) `C:\Users\xyz\AppData\Local\Google\AndroidStudio20xx.x\log`
2. Look for Gradle file - under `gradle-wrapper.properties` and App level `build.gradle`. Should be the same.
3. Firewall - It may be blocking downloading of required libs solution.